# Mannually calling jquery mouseover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

the jquery has a set of functions in which i want to call the onmouseover function manually.

my index.php consist of a div in which it has a ease-in-out transition [like this DEMO](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircleHoverEffects/index2.html) on mouseover event. i want to control the ease-in-out transition on a button click.

when i searched on this topic,i found it can be done by `if($("#my_btn_id").trigger('mouseover'))` . but i tried and i could not find a solution for this.

Comment: Without any ifs, just `$("#my_btn_id").trigger('mouseover')` will work.

Comment: `if($("#my_btn_id").trigger('mouseover'))` would always evaluated to true.. since `.trigger()` would return back the jquery object for chaining..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n9yett0a/ ?

Comment: @ nicael, did not work, is it really a mouseover function in demo.?

Comment: @ShifanaMubi Be sure, that you're triggering `mouseover` after the definition of `mouseover` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/dghfwz5e/1/

modify css which was on `:hover` change it to class `.hover` and toggle it using `jQuery`

```js
$('.ch-item').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

```css
.ch-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(200, 95, 66, 0.4), inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.ch-img-3 {
  background-image: url(http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircleHoverEffects/images/5.jpg);
}
.ch-info {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /*for a smooth font */
}
.ch-info h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 65px 0 0 0;
  height: 110px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.ch-info p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.ch-info p a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.ch-info p a:hover {
  color: #fff222;
  color: rgba(255, 242, 34, 0.8);
}
.ch-item.hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 110px rgba(200, 95, 66, 0.4), inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.ch-item.hover .ch-info {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
body {
  font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
  background: #f9f9f9 url(../images/bg.jpg);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
a {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.clr {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.container > header {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
}
.container > header h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #777;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.container > header h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
  color: #888;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
/* Header Style */

.codrops-top {
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 11px;
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.codrops-top a {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
}
.codrops-top a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.codrops-top span.right {
  float: right;
}
.codrops-top span.right a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
/* Demo Buttons Style */

.codrops-demos {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}
.codrops-demos a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  padding: 0px 6px;
  color: #aaa;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #ffffff;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(47%, #f6f6f6), color-stop(100%, #ededed));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.codrops-demos a:hover {
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
}
.codrops-demos a:active {
  background: #fff;
}
.codrops-demos a.current-demo,
.codrops-demos a.current-demo:hover {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-color: #d9d9d9;
  color: #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f6f6f6', endColorstr='#f6f6f6', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
.support-note span {
  color: #ac375d;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.no-cssanimations .support-note span.no-cssanimations,
.no-csstransforms .support-note span.no-csstransforms,
.no-csstransforms3d .support-note span.no-csstransforms3d,
.no-csstransitions .support-note span.no-csstransitions {
  display: block;
}
.ch-grid {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.ch-grid:after,
.ch-item:before {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
.ch-grid:after {
  clear: both;
}
.ch-grid li {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="main">
  <ul class="ch-grid">
    <li>
      <div class="ch-item ch-img-3">
        <div class="ch-info">
          <h3>Cylon</h3>

          <p>by Daniel Nyari <a href="http://drbl.in/eNXY">View on Dribbble</a>

          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="ch-item ch-img-3">
        <div class="ch-info">
          <h3>Cylon</h3>

          <p>by Daniel Nyari <a href="http://drbl.in/eNXY">View on Dribbble</a>

          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks vitorino for the specific answer, its worked in code snippet and jsfiddle too. but not works in project(localhost).

Comment: no errors. yes jquery added as per the code <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: i didn't get the answer, kindly help me please

Comment: you have changed the css? from `:hover` to `.hover`

Comment: yes, i copy pasted the above css too, but no +ve results

Comment: check if your html structure is like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/dghfwz5e/2/)

Comment: yes, worked, thanks a lot sir. you finalized ma 2 days